# Keeping a common legend scale in ggplot with shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a shiny app that takes a dataset spanning 8 years and splits it by month. Then with a date slider, it creates the ggplot using just the data from that month.

The ggplot being used is:

```
  ggplot() +
      geom_map(
        map = wrld, data = wrld, aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
        color = "grey", fill ="white", size=0.1
      ) +
      geom_point(
        data = dat(), aes(longitude, latitude, size = freq), 
        shape=21, fill = "red", color = "white", stroke=0.01
      ) +
      scale_size(name = "# IPs", label=scales::comma, range = c(1,10)) +
      ggalt::coord_proj("+proj=wintri") +
      ggthemes::theme_map() +
      theme(legend.justification = "center") +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
      labs(title=paste("Post frequency ", shiny())) +
      annotate("text", x = 0, y = -60, label = "Bots")
```

The reactive elements `dat()` and `shiny()` are created by this code:

```
  shiny <- reactive({
    format(as.Date(input$slider), "%Y-%m")
  })
  dat <- reactive({
    count <- count(data.frame(splitted[[shiny()]]))
    counted <- ddply(count,"city_name",summarize,longitude=mean(longitude),latitude=mean(latitude),freq=sum(freq))
    counted <- counted[order(counted$freq),]
    counted[nrow(counted),1] <- "Bots"
    counted[nrow(counted),2:3] <- c(0,-55)
    counted
  })
```

An example of `splitted` is shown:

```
> head(splitted['2012-07'])
$`2012-07`
                                         city_name longitude latitude   dateline       ipaddress                date
348812                                    Oak Lawn  -87.7516  41.7143 1341093604   67.175.106.62 2012-07-01 00:00:04
348813                                    Richmond  -84.2955  37.7546 1341093617    76.177.28.76 2012-07-01 00:00:17
348814                                    Lynbrook  -73.6741  40.6571 1341093624   72.68.156.111 2012-07-01 00:00:24
348815                                    Oak Lawn  -87.7516  41.7143 1341093680   67.175.106.62 2012-07-01 00:01:20
348816                                   Las Vegas -115.0669  36.1730 1341093690   24.253.64.114 2012-07-01 00:01:30
348817                                    Richmond  -84.2955  37.7546 1341093698    76.177.28.76 2012-07-01 00:01:38
348818                                   Cleveland  -83.7500  34.5839 1341093716  67.140.236.247 2012-07-01 00:01:56
348819                                   Las Vegas -115.0669  36.1730 1341093782   24.253.64.114 2012-07-01 00:03:02
348820                                    Lynbrook  -73.6741  40.6571 1341093826   72.68.156.111 2012-07-01 00:03:46
348821                                    Oak Lawn  -87.7516  41.7143 1341093886   67.175.106.62 2012-07-01 00:04:46
```

The shiny app is working fine, and the map updates properly. The issue is, the legend scale updates each map. The result is that the map 'looks' the same no matter what actual level of frequency. Look at these two months:
[image]
[image]

The size of the dots are the same, even though the frequency in the first picture is up to 4,000, and the frequency in the second picture is up to 80. The reason for this can be understood when looking at the overall posts per day over time:
[image]

I'm not really understanding what I need to change on the ggplot in order to force the same 'size scale' on all time periods.

The entire app.R file can be viewed at https://pastebin.com/WjedbxT3

Regrettably, I can't share the dataset of 887,000 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. I thought that I had tried this already.

```
scale_size(name = "# IPs", label=scales::comma, range = c(2,25), limits = c(1,5000))
```